# Tweepy Error 214: User is not a valid Long

Tags: python, tweepy

This has been bugging me for quite a while now. Im unable to find the error code anywhere on the Tweepy documentation and there are no questions online addressing this error code which is strange. I am trying to send a direct message with send_direct_message method, which looks like this on the documentation:

```
API.send_direct_message(recipient_id, text[, quick_reply_type][, attachment_type][, attachment_media_id])
```

This is my code (excluding all the authentication etc:

```
text = "Hi user"
user = "user"
api.send_direct_message(user, text)
```

and this is the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 34, in <module> 
    api.send_direct_message(user, text)
   line 458, in send_direct_message
    return self._send_direct_message(json_payload=json_payload)
   line 252, in _call
    return method.execute()
   line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)

tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 214, 'message': "event.message_create.target.recipient_id: 'user' is not a valid Long"}]
```

Only thing I could think of here is that its detecting my userID as longtitude for some reason, otherwise I have no clue as to why im getting this error message. Please teach me python Gods.

Answer (score 0):

User id is a number and represents the ID of the Twitter user (not the username)

```
text = "Hi user"
user = "123" # valid ID
api.send_direct_message(user, text)
```

You can obtain the user ID in 2 ways:

if you are replying to a DM you can just get it from the message you have received

```
user = message.message_create["sender_id"]
```

alternatively you can fetch it with an API call (as long as you know the username)

```
user = api.get_user("username")
print(user.id_str)
```